# How to get Celery to load the config from command line?

Tags: python, celery

I am attempting to use `celery worker` to load a config file at the command line:

`celery worker --config=my_settings_module`

This doesn't appear to work.  celery worker starts and uses its default settings (which include assuming that there is a RabbitMQ server available at localhost:5672) In my config, I would like to point celery to a different place.  When I change the amqp settings in the config file to something,  Celery didn't appear to care.  It still shows the default RabbitMQ settings.

I also tried something bogus

`celery worker --config=this_file_does_not_exist`

And Celery once again did not care.  The worker started and attached to the default RabbitMQ.  It's not even looking at the --config setting

I read about how Celery lazy loads.  I'm not sure that has anything to do with this.

How do I get celery worker to honor the --config setting?

Comment: From the directory that contains your module (that is, one directory up from where you have your celery.py), try this: celery worker -A *module_name*

Comment: That will identify and load an app module.  It can accomplish that if I specify it.  But it doesn't help me get the --config command line argument to work. How do I get --config to do something?

Answer (score 4):

If you give some invalid module name or a module name which is not in `PYTHONPATH`, say `celery worker --config=invalid_foo`, celery will ignore it.

You can verify this by creating a simple config file.

```
$ celery worker -h

--config=CONFIG       Name of the configuration module
```

As mentioned in celery worker help, you should pass configuration module. Otherwise it will raise an error.

If you just run

```
celery worker
```

it will start worker and its output **will be colored**.

In the same directory, create a file called `c.py` with this line.

```
CELERYD_LOG_COLOR = False
```

Now run

```
celery worker --config=c
```

it will start worker and its output will **not be colored**.

If you run `celery worker --config=c.py`, it will raise an error.

```
celery.utils.imports.NotAPackage: Error: Module 'c.py' doesn't exist, or it's not a valid Python module name.
Did you mean 'c'?
```

Comment: This answer does not actually answer the question. If you read the original post, the writer says he's tried to set the --config= and it's being ignored. I'm running into the same problem at the mo'.

Comment: If you give invalid module name or module which is not in python path, celery will ignore it. Make sure your module is in python path and then pass it to `--config`, then celery will pick it up. Does that help?

Comment: If I read it correctly (maybe I didn't) the author had tried using... oh wait, *that's* the important bit? Does the config module have to be in the python path? If so, I didn't pick that up from your answer (and my apologies.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error, but I eventually figured out that I had made simple option naming mistakes in the configuration module itself which were not obvious at all.

You see, when you start out and follow the tutorial, you will end up with something that looks like this in your main module:

```
app = Celery('foo', broker='amqp://user:pass@example.com/vsrv', backend='rpc://')
```

Which works fine, but then later as you add more and more configuration options you decide to move the options to a separate file, at which point you go ahead and just copy+paste and split the options into lines until it looks like this:

Naïve my_settings.py:

```
broker='amqp://user:pass@example.com/vsrv'
backend='rpc://'
result_persistent=True
task_acks_late=True
# ... etc. etc.
```

And there you just fooled yourself! Because in a settings module **the options are called `broker_url` and `result_backend`** instead of just `broker` and `backend` as they would be called in the instantiation above.

Corrected my_settings.py:

```
broker_url='amqp://user:pass@example.com/vsrv'
result_backend='rpc://'
result_persistent=True
task_acks_late=True
# ... etc. etc.
```

And all of a sudden, your worker boots up just fine with all settings in place.

I hope this will cure a few headaches of fellow celery newbies like us.

Further note:
You can test that celery in fact *does not* ignore your file by placing a print-statement (or print function call if you're on Py3) into the settings module.